# CSS box-shadow alternative to draw realistic cloud?

Tags: html, css, frontend, webkit

I'm currently designing a cloud to use for a personal website.
Right now, I'm following the [CSS Tricks tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/drawing-realistic-clouds-with-svg-and-css/) to draw a beautiful and realistic cloud. (using filter, box-shadow, border-radius, etc)
[image]

The cloud renders beautifully and does not lag on scroll on the desktop but it lags incredibly so on any mobile device like the iPhone and iPad. This seems to be a known issues that has persisted over the decade.

I'm stomped as to what my alternatives are. If anyone has advice, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @tacoshy the tuto he's following rely on SVG by the way and there isn't a lot of elements like I was expecting

Comment: @tacoshy You're right, I've been tinkering with Adobe drawing tools to design one myself for a while which is time consuming but should be rewarding. The website is mostly 2-D so wanted something 3-D to balance it out. Thanks for your two cents anyway!

Comment: @TemaniAfif *she* Yep, I might just stick to basic, zero css SVGs for mobile. Thanks everyone.